# Changing header bg colour React bootstrap

Tags: sass, react-bootstrap

Trying to make a website with react bootstrap and cannot change the colour of my header. Currently it is coming up as the default primary colour when I want to change it to green.

```
  <header className="bg-primary">
    <Container>
    <Navbar expand="md" variant="dark">
      <Navbar.Brand href="/">{siteTitle}</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbarResponsive" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarResponsive">
        <Nav as="ul" className="ml-auto">
          <Nav.Item as="li">
            <Link to="/about" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">About</Link>
          </Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Item as="li">
            <Link to="/projects" className="nav-link" activeClassName="active">Projects</Link>
          </Nav.Item>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
    </Container>
    
  </header>
)
```

I have created my own scss file

```
// change the theme
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #44bb88,
  "danger": #44bb88,
);


// Import Bootstrap and its default variables
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

I have also imported this file at the top of my code

```
import '../themes/main.scss';
```

Although the colour remains the default blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldnt work out what was going wrong but I successfully changed the colour by adding a new color to theme colors and then setting that as the bg color.

`<header className="bg-main">`

```
$theme-colors: (
  "main": #44bb88,
  "danger": #44bb88,
);
```